# The last modified times and last access times are wrong

Tags: samba

The samba server reports the same creation time all 3 values of creation time, last modified time and last access time to the clients.

How do I get it reporting the correct times?

```
$ samba --version
Version 4.17.7-Ubuntu
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which back-end file system on the server you use? Which kind of time stamps it supports? What are mount options (e.g. if `noatime` is present it will make it work like you observe)? Also note Linux's standard `stat()` system call simply [doesn't report creation time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)); while ext4 finally got it into the inode (recently), one needs to use alternate `statx()` call to retrieve it. Other file systems might not have this information at all, so nothing for Samba to report. Chances are, it is *impossible* to report correct creation time.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov
Oh, thanks for your question. I realize the samba share is actually hosted on Synology DSM. I should have asked on Synology forums as well.

$ uname -a
Linux DS918Plus 4.4.302+ #64570 SMP Thu Jul 20 00:07:29 CST 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_apollolake_918+

But the files were written from ubuntu through samba share.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov
Running command stat does give me all times correctly.

$ stat pga-2023.09.02-19.25.00.log
  File: pga-2023.09.02-19.25.00.log
  Size: 13852347   Blocks: 27056      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 54h/84d Inode: 1965        Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1059/   nuc13)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2023-09-02 19:55:12.809187728 +0100
Modify: 2023-09-02 19:25:00.000000000 +0100
Change: 2023-09-02 19:55:12.808187710 +0100
 Birth: -

Comment: That must have been added [into the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1142911/edit). It is unreadable in comments. Well, I can see the "birth" (creation) timestamp is already lost :) There might be a bug in Samba as well, for example [in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/2007055). If that bug comes from upstream, DSM must have been inherited it too. Also, it is kinda silly to use Samba to share files between Linuxes. NFS should work better, as it is native.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov
Thanks for your reply.
Yeah, I understand NFS is a better choice for *NIX. However, I would like to minimize the attack vector; hence, enabling as few services as possible. Samba cannot be eliminated as most clients are running macOS. Furthermore, I think the IP based authentication is insecure as well.

Comment: macOS is [Unix-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)), so NFS is native to it too, while Samba is foreign. And, NFS supports Kerberos authentication (though I don't know if it is possible to use it on DSM). All in all, using it you'll have file system which blends much better into the environment than Samba.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov
You have a point. Yeah, macOS is UNIX. But the preferred network protocol is SMBv3 though.
1, NFS mount is not supported on Finder, the default file manager on mac.
2, Time Machine, the built-in backup manager, does not work on NFS either.

Nonetheless, I might explore NFS share later but it cannot replace SMB. At best, just a complement. NFS still expanses the attack vector. :(